# Html5 number can't extract value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have some HTML code :

```
    <div class="row">
     <label class="span3" for="WidgetWidthProduct">Widget width</label>
     <input type="number" class="span1" min="2" max="12" id="WidgetWidthProduct" value="3" />
    </div>
```

I'm trying to find the value after someone changed the input,but i'm keep getting "0"??

```
    alert($("#WidgetWidthProduct").val());
```

Any help?
Thx

Comment: Are u using this from within a `$(document).ready(function() {...});`

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/SDKw7/ Perhaps you need to show a bit more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you wrap `alert($("#WidgetWidthProduct").val());` inside of a doc ready?

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eonasdan/wN55H/) works just fine

```
 $(function () {
    alert($("#WidgetWidthProduct").val());
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

is Your Code Run After Load Page? Became sure about duplicate element **id**

Comment: Solved duplicate element id was the culprit